# How to show that there is an unique multiplication on a group topology in the following problem?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $(X,+,e)$ be a topological group with identity $e$ and multiplication $+$. Suppose that $X$ is connected, locally path connected, and semilocally simply connected.

Given a subgroup $G$ of $\pi_1(X,e)$, define $P(X,e)$ as the set of all paths in $X$ beginning at $e$. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $P(X,e)$ with $f\sim g$ if and only if $f(1)=g(1)$ and $[f \star g^{-1} ] \in G$. We write the equivalence class of $f$ by $<f>$.

Let $\tilde{X}_G=\{<f> \mid f \in P(X,e)\}$. We define $p:\tilde{X}_G \longrightarrow X$ with $p([f])=f(1)$. I have shown that $p$ is continuous and a covering map.

Now construct a multiplication $\cdot$ on $\tilde{X}_G$ with $<f> \cdot <g>=<f \oplus g>$ where $(f \oplus g )(t)=f(t)+g(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. I also have shown that $(\tilde{X}_G, \cdot, <\varepsilon>)$ is a topological group where $\varepsilon(t)=e$ and $p$ is a group homomorphism.

In book "Topology 2nd " (James Munkres ), it is claimed that there is a unique multiplication on $\tilde{X}_G$ such that $\tilde{X}_G$ becomes a topological group with identity $<\varepsilon>$ and $p$ is a homomorphism. I try to show that if we have another multiplication $\tilde{\cdot}$ on $\tilde{X}_G$ such that $\tilde{X}_G$ becomes a topological group with identity $<\varepsilon>$ and $p$ is a homomorphism, then $<f> \cdot <g>=<f> \tilde{\cdot} <g>$ for all $<f>, <g> \in \tilde{X}_G$ by this way :

Since $p$ is a homomorphism, $$p( <f> \tilde{\cdot} <g>)=p(<f>)+p(<g>)=p(<f> \cdot <g>)=f(1)+g(1).$$ Let $x=f(1)+g(1)$. Because $p$ is a covering map, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $p^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{j \in J} V_j$ where $V_j$ is open in $\tilde{X}_G$, $V_i \cap V_j$ is empty and $p|_{V_j}:V_j \longrightarrow U$ is homeomorphism for all $j \in J$. Then there is an unique $V_1$ such that $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <g> \in V_1$, Similary, there is an unique $V_2$ such that $<f> \cdot <g> \in V_2$.
But, I don't have any idea after this step. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't thought through the details (and I don't really have time to do so now), but if we fix a point $<f>\in \tilde{X}_G$, and let $Z = \{<g>\in \tilde{X}_G: <f>\tilde{\cdot} <g> = <f>\cdot <f>\}$, then note that $Z$ is not empty because it contains $\varepsilon$.  Then try to show that $Z$ is both open and closed.  If you can also show that $\tilde{X}_G$ is connected, then it follows that $Z = \tilde{X}_G$.  Doing thing for all $<f>$ then gives the result.  You can prove that $Z$ is open as follows.....

Comment: Pick $<g>\in Z$, so $<f>\tilde{\cdot}<g> = <f>\cdot<g>$.  As you did in your post, set $x = p(<f>\cdot<g>)$ and use evenly covered neighborhoods.  The key point is that since you already know that $<g>\in Z$, it follows that (in the notation of your last paragraph), $V_1 = V_2$.  Now, let $<h> \in V_1$.  Then $p(<f>\tilde{\cdot} <h>) = p(<f>\cdot<g>)$ (since they are both $p(<f>) + p(<g>)$.  Since $p$ is invertible on $V_1$, it now follows that $<f>\tilde{\cdot} <h> = <f>\cdot<h>$ on $V_1$.  In other words, $V_1\subseteq Z$.  Hence $Z$ is open.

Comment: (Last comment from me:  Personally, I think the notation $<f>$ is ugly and would far prefer $\langle f \rangle$ which can be achieved using \langle and \rangle.)

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I have shown that $\tilde{X}_G$ is path connected, so that it is connected. It is remain to show that $Z$ is closed and we will get $Z=\tilde{X}_G$. I will revise the notation $<f>$.

Comment: And for the set $Z$, is it $Z=\{\langle g \rangle \mid \langle f \rangle \tilde{\cdot} \langle g \rangle=\langle f \rangle \cdot \langle g \rangle\}$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry, Sir. I have learned your proof about $Z$ is open. We pick $<g> \in \tilde{X}_G$ and find an open neighborhood $O$ of $<g>$ such that $O \subseteq Z$. But $V_1$ is an open neighborhood of $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <g>$. But, we can't ensure that $V_1$ contains $<g>$.

Comment: Sir, I tried to prove $Z$ is open by this way : Let $<g> \in Z$. It means $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <g>=<f> \cdot <g>$. Set $x=p(<f> \tilde{\cdot} <g>)=p(<f> \cdot <g>)$. Then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ which is evenly covered by $p$. Therefore there is a unique open set $V_1 \subseteq \tilde{X}_G$ containing $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <g>=<f> \cdot <g>$. Since $\cdot$ and $\tilde{\cdot}$ are continuous, there exist open set $W_1,W_2,W_1',W_2'$ such that $<f> \in W_1 \cap W_1'$ and $<g> \in W_2 \cap W_2'$. Let $<h> \in W_2 \cap W_2'$. We get $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <h>,<f> \cdot <h> \in V_1$.

Comment: (Continued) Since $p$ is homomorphism, $p(<f> \tilde{\cdot} <h>=p(<f>)+p(<h>)=p(<f> \cdot <h>)$. Hence  $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <h>=<f> \cdot <h>$ since $p$ is bijective. We can conclude that $<h> \in Z$,$W_2 \cap W_2' \subseteq Z$ and $Z$ is open.

Comment: For $Z$ is closed : Let $<h> \in Z^c$ (complement of $Z$ ). It means $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <h>\neq <f> \cdot <h>$. Set $x=p(<f> \tilde{\cdot} <h>)=p(<f> \cdot <h>)$. Then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ which is evenly covered by $p$. Suppose that $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <h> \in V_1$ and $<f> \cdot <h> \in V_2$. SInce $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <h>\neq <f> \cdot <h>$, $V_1 \cap V_2=\emptyset$. Again, since $\tilde{\cdot}$ and $\cdot$ are continuous, there exist $W_1,W_2,W_1', W_2'$ such that $<f> \in W_1 \cap W_1'$ and $<h> \in W_2 \cap W_2'$ and $W_1 \tilde{cdot} W_2 \subseteq V_1$ and

Comment: $W_1' \tilde{cdot} W_2' \subseteq V_2$. Let $<g> \in W_2 \cap W_2'$. We have $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <g> \in V_1$ and $<f> \cdot <g> \in V_2$. Then $<f> \tilde{\cdot} <g> \in V_1 \neq <f> \cdot <g>$ since $V_1$ and $V_2$ are disjoint. Therefore, $<h>$ is an interior point of $Z^c$. Thus, $Z$ is closed.

Comment: Yes, something like this should work perfectly, but I'm not sure why you're using 4 open sets involving $W$....

Comment: Thank your Sir. I am using 4 open sets $W$ because $V_1$ is an open neighborhood of $<f> \cdot <g>$. It doesn't mean $V_1$ is an open neighborhood of $<g>$.

Comment: Yes, I agree that $V_1$ need not contain $<g>$.  Anyway, please feel free to write up all your comments as an answer.  Or, I can write up an answer if you prefer.

Comment: Yes Sir, please,  I appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You said in the comments that you've already shown that $\tilde{X}_G$ is connected, so let's take advantage of that.  Also, I'm gonna use the notation $\langle f\rangle$ instead of $<f>$, just because I think it looks nicer.

Now fix $\langle f\rangle \in \tilde{X}_G$.  Let $$Z = \{\langle g\rangle\in\tilde{X}_G: \langle f\rangle \cdot \langle g\rangle=  \langle f\rangle\tilde{\cdot}\langle g\rangle\}.$$

Note first that by hypothesis, $\langle\varepsilon\rangle\in Z$, so $Z\neq \emptyset$.  Hence, if we can show that $Z$ is both open and closed, then it follows form connectedness of $\tilde{X}_G$ that $Z = \tilde{X}_G$.  Because $\langle f\rangle$ is arbitrary, this will establish the fact that the two multiplications agree.

**$Z$ is open** Let $\langle g\rangle\in Z$.  This means that $\langle f\rangle \cdot\langle g \rangle = \langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot}\langle g\rangle.$  Set $x = p(\langle f \rangle \cdot \langle g\rangle).$

Because $p$ is a covering, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ for which $p^{-1}(V) = \coprod V_i$ with each $p|_{V_i}:V_i\rightarrow V$ a homeomorphism.  Since $p(\langle f \rangle \cdot\langle g\rangle)\in V$, there is some $V_i$, say $V_1$, which contains $\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle g\rangle.$

Because $(\tilde{X}_G,\cdot)$ is a topological group, left multiplication by $\langle f\rangle^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism, so $W:=\langle f \rangle^{-1}\cdot V$ is an open set.  Likewise, $\tilde{W} = \langle f \rangle^{-1}\tilde{\cdot} V$ is an open set.  (Careful, the notation $\langle f\rangle^{-1}$ used for $W$ refers to the $\cdot$-inverse, while it refers to the $\tilde{\cdot}$-inverse for $\tilde{W}$.

Note that $\langle g\rangle = \langle f \rangle^{-1}(\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle g\rangle)$, so $\langle g\rangle\in W$.  That is, $W$ is an open neighborhood of $\langle g\rangle$.  Likewise, $\tilde{W}$ is an open neighborhood of $\langle g\rangle$.  Thus, $U:= W\cap \tilde{W}$ is an open neighborhood of $\langle g\rangle$.

We claim that $U\subseteq Z$.  So see this, pick $\langle h\rangle \in U$.  Then $$\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle h\rangle \in \langle f \rangle \cdot U\subseteq \langle f \rangle \cdot W = \langle f\rangle \cdot \langle f\rangle^{-1} \cdot V_1 = V_1,$$ so $\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle h\rangle \in V_1$.  Likewise, $\langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot} \langle h\rangle \in V_1$.

Further, $p(\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle h \rangle) = f(1) + h(1) = p(\langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot} \langle h \rangle)$ by hypothesis.  Because $p|_{V_1}$ is injective, it now follows that $\langle f \rangle \cdot \langle h\rangle = \langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot}\langle h \rangle$.  In otherwords, $h\in Z$.  This is establishes that $U\subseteq Z$, so $Z$ is open.

**$Z$ is closed**.  We will show the complement is open.  So, suppose $\langle g\rangle \notin Z$.  As in the open case, if we set $x = p(\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle g\rangle)$ (which is equal to $p(\langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot} \langle g\rangle)$ because both are equal to $f(1) + g(1)$), we have an open set $V$ around $x$ for which $p^{-1}(V) = \coprod V_i$ with $p|_{V_i}:V_i\rightarrow V$ a homeomorphism.

We let $V_1$ be the $V_i$ containing $\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle g\rangle$ and we let $V_2$ be the $V_i$ containing $\langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot} \langle g \rangle$.  Note that $V_1\neq V_2$ (because other wise, injectivity of $p$ on $V_1$ would force $\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle g\rangle = \langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot} \langle g\rangle,$), so $V_1\cap V_2 = \emptyset$.

Create the open set $U$ similarly to the open case:  $U = \langle f\rangle^{-1} V_1\cap \langle f\rangle^{-1}\tilde{\cdot} V_2$.  Since $\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle g\rangle \in V_1$ and $\langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot} \langle g\rangle \in V_2$, we see that $\langle g\rangle \in U$.

We claim that $U$ is a subset of the complement of $Z$.  To that end, let $\langle h\rangle \in U$.  Then $\langle f \rangle \cdot \langle h\rangle \in V_1$ while $\langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot} \langle h\rangle \in V_2$.  Because $V_1\cap V_2 = \emptyset$, $\langle f\rangle \cdot \langle h\rangle \neq \langle f\rangle \tilde{\cdot}\langle h\rangle$.  That is, $\langle h\rangle \notin Z$.  Thus, $U$ is a subset of the complement of $Z$, so $Z$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your another point of view. I think it is more efficient than my own work. I forgot to use the fact that if $O$ is an open set then $x \cdot O$ is also open. Once again, thank you very much Sir.